# Erro na hora de passar uma lista para dentro de uma key de um dicionario

Tags: python

```
#variavies de controle:
open = 1 #Controle a abertura do aplicativo inteiro.
cjogo = c = 0

#dicionarios:
temporario = {}
templista = []
lista_jogadores = []

while True:
    cjogo = 0
    c+=1
    templista.clear()
    temporario['jogador'] = str(input('Digite o nome do jogador: '))
    temporario['qtdJogos'] = int(input('Digite o numero de jogos: '))
    if temporario['qtdJogos'] > 0:
        while cjogo < temporario['qtdJogos']:
            r = int(input('Numeros de gols do {}° jogo: '.format(cjogo+1)))
            templista.append(r)
            cjogo+=1
        temporario['gols'] = templista
    else:
        temporario['gols'] = 0
    
    lista_jogadores.append(temporario.copy())   
    print(lista_jogadores)


#No resultado quando se tem mais de 1 jogador registrado os gols deles ficam iguais e eu não sei porque a key gols esta ficando igual para todos :( ja revisei o codigo mas não achei o erro logico.
```

Comment: Descobri o erro fazendo diversas tentativas e erro e o que notei(posso estar errado) é que quando você atribui diretamente uma lista a uma key o valor daquela lista fica em "sincronia" com o dicionario então tem que se usar uma copia utilizando-se "lista[:]"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu erro é exatamente o que você conseguiu encontrar. Em python, como listas são *mutáveis* (uma característica de alguns tipos embutidos do python), limpar a lista não apaga ela da memória, nem remove as referências anteriores. Então se você faz

```
# primeira lista adicionada
templista = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# cria dicionario com referencia a primeira lista
dicionario = {'gols 1': templista}

# limpa os valores da lista
templista.clear()

#
templista.append(1)
dicionario['gols 2'] = templista
```

ambas as chaves no dicionário terão a mesma informação ([1])

Isso acontece porque o nome "templista" não foi atribuido a outro objeto.

Imagine o seguinte, o Python cria na memória do computador uma região para armazenar os objetos da lista. Você remove (com o clear()) os elementos da lista, mas a lista ainda está lá. Quando você faz `templista.append(r)` você não está criando uma nova lista, você está adicionando elementos a lista que foi limpada 4 passos antes.

A consequência disso é que toda chave do dicionário aponta para a mesma lista, já que `templista` tem seus valores modificados, mas nunca sua identidade (ela sempre permanece sendo a mesma lista)

```
temporario['gols'] = templista
```

Uma forma mais simples de você resolver esse problema é criar a variável templista dentro do while, substituindo o `templista.clear()` por `templista = []`